# Why does window.showModalDialog throw an "Access is Denied" error?

Tags: internet-explorer, modal-dialog, legacy, showmodaldialog

I'm working on a legacy application that uses the IE-only `window.showModalDialog` command to display web pages in a modal dialog.

Recently, I tried logging into the application as a different user and began seeing a dialog that says "Access is Denied" whenever the page tries to open one of these pages.

What could have happened to cause this problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The security settings in your browser must be set lax enough to allow the operation to take place.  To make it work, go to the "Security" tab of add the web application to IE's "Trusted Sites" and set the security level for "Trusted Sites" to "Low"

It should not be necessary to restart IE.